# Not able to open source file and debug in angular 16

Tags: angular, chrome-debugging, angular16

Updated my angular project from 7.2 to 16 in that case i'm not able to debug and not able to open source file
is any solution available for it?

added  "configurations": {
"production": {
"sourceMap": true,
}
but still not working this

Comment: Are you running in development configuration? E.g. `default: “production”` will make `ng serve` run production